# Oracle sql to count instances of different values in single column

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table with status column. I want an Oracle sql query which will list me count of rows in each status in only one row.
for eg if my table is

```
Table A
Id       Status  Fkey
1         20      500
2         20      500  
3         30      501
4         40      501
5         30      502
```

Output should be

```
Fkey     Count_status20     Count_status30    Count_status40
500        2                      0                 0
501        0                      1                 1
```

A slight twist here

```
Table B 
FKey TKey 
500   1001 
501   1001
502   1002
```

Now Output should be

```
TKey Count_status20     Count_status30    Count_status40 
1001     2                     1                    1 
1002     0                     1                    0
```

Comment: I want to so something like for col in ('20' as Count_Status20, 
              '30' or '40' as Count_Status30,
              '50' as Count_Status50) I get syntax error when trying to do. How is it possible to aggregate columns ?

Comment: @Harsha ... my suggestion is to re-accept the answer and ask a new one with your new requirements.

Comment: Can you post a new question explaining with sample data, what you want for a final result?  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please do not modify an existing question like this.  If you had a question with a working answer, leave it and open a new question about the issue.

Comment: Ok I did post a new question here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258990/oracle-sql-to-count-instances-of-different-values-in-single-column-continuatio

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 11g, then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select tkey, status, 
    status as col
  from tableB b
  left join tableA a
    on a.fkey = b.fkey
) src
pivot
(
  count(status)
  for col in ('20' as Count_Status20, 
              '30' as Count_Status30,
              '40' as Count_Status40)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/823de/1)

If you are not using Oracle11g, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select tkey, 
  count(case when status = 20 then 1 else null end) as Count_Status20,
  count(case when status = 30 then 1 else null end) as Count_Status30,
  count(case when status = 40 then 1 else null end) as Count_Status40
from tableB b
left join tableA a
  on b.fkey = a.fkey
group by tkey
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/823de/2)

Comment: @Harsha please see my edit, the code is the same you will just join the tables together

Comment: Using you query I get counts in multiple rows TKey Count_status20     Count_status30    Count_status40 
1001     2                     0                    0 
1001     0                     1                    0 1001 0 0 1 1002 1 0 0

Comment: In output I want one row per TKey

Comment: @Harsha which version of the query are you using?  If you are using the `PIVOT` and if you are including any additional fields in the subquery then the items will not group by correctly.

Comment: @swasheck: my bad but I had a slight twist to the original problem

Comment: I just used the COUNT(case-statement) method, just because it's easy to read and understand, without learning the pivot thing (which I'm not handy with yet).  Worked great.

Answer (score 3):

```
select fkey,
       sum(case when status = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as count_status20,
       sum(case when status = 30 then 1 else 0 end) as count_status30,
       sum(case when status = 40 then 1 else 0 end) as count_status40,
from your_table
group by fkey
```