# Oracle sql to count instances of different values in single column - continuation

Tags: oracle

This is in continuation to an earlier question I had posted
Here is the link
[Oracle sql to count instances of different values in single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238142/oracle-sql-to-count-instances-of-different-values-in-single-column)

In further continuation to the pivot query, I am trying to do something like

for col in (
Count_status20 as col20, 
Count_status30 or Count_status40 as col30,
Count_status50 as col50)
The input remaning the same as earlier question.

Basically here I am trying to sum statuses in 30 or 40 as one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
select *
from
(
  select tkey, status, 
    decode(status, 30, 30, 40, 30,status) as col
  from tableB b
  left join tableA a
    on a.fkey = b.fkey
) src
pivot
(
  count(status)
  for col in ('20' as Count_Status20, 
              '30' as Count_Status3040,
              '50' as Count_Status50)
) piv;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef499/5) is a fiddle