# Output counts in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a status column which will only ever contain three distinct values. I need to get a count for each, but I need to output them on a single row. So rather than:

```
`status`  | `count` 
 status1  |  100
 status2  |  101
 status3  |  102
```

I want:

```
`status1` | `status2` | `status3`
 100      |  101      |  102
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I'm not seeing it.

edit: Managed to get it to work using an answer from [Oracle sql to count instances of different values in single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238142/oracle-sql-to-count-instances-of-different-values-in-single-column):

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'STATUS1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS STATUS1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'STATUS2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS STATUS2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'STATUS3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS STATUS3
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: `LISTAGG` is the way

Comment: I should clarify that I want these as separate fields. Question updated.

Comment: So it is simply pivot. Also very commom duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, real helpful.